# Undefined array key 0 in Blade template Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm not sure why I am getting this error in my blade template although everything seems to be fine.

```
Undefined array key 0 (View: ...
```

And the blade template code goes like:

```
@foreach($offers as $offer)
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-2 mb-4">
        <div class="card car-card">
            <div
                class="card-header p-0 mx-3 mt-3 position-relative z-index-1">
                @if($offer["images"] !== null)

                    {{-- {{dd($offer)}}--}}
                    <img
                        src="{{$offer["images"][0]["url"]}}" <<-- THE ERROR IS HERE !! 
                        alt="car image"
                        class="w-100 position-relative z-index-2 pt-2 car-front-image"/>
                @else
                    <img v-else
                         class="w-100 position-relative z-index-2 pt-2 car-front-image"
                         src="/api/image/default/car/"
                         alt="car image">
                @endif
            </div> ... the rest of the code
```

the offer output is:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that one of your offers, not exactly the first one, has no images? Becaus if you use dd in your Loop you will only see the first offer. But it is possible that the error happens on the 10nth offer.
Please use `dd($offers)` and look at all the images of all offers.

Alternatively you could use @if to check if there is an image, if not display an upload button or some text like "no image"

Answer (score 1):

As posted in comment by @Aless55 there may be empty array of `images`. The reason because `@if($offer["images"] !== null)` is failing because even though your array is `[]` it will not be `null`

```
$array = [];

if($array){
  dd('not empty');
}else{
  dd('empty');
}
```

So by doing

```
@if($offer["images"])

                    {{-- {{dd($offer)}}--}}
                    <img
                        src="{{$offer["images"][0]["url"]}}" <<-- THE ERROR IS HERE !! 
                        alt="car image"
                        class="w-100 position-relative z-index-2 pt-2 car-front-image"/>
                @else
                    <img v-else
                         class="w-100 position-relative z-index-2 pt-2 car-front-image"
                         src="/api/image/default/car/"
                         alt="car image">
                @endif
```